# Why do some apt-get installs restart mySQL?

Tags: mysql, apt

I ran into an odd situation where installing a package via `apt-get` caused running (production!) instances of mysqld to restart on some 16.04 Linux servers.

We ran `sudo apt-get install -y iotop` on four servers. On three of the servers the installation failed stating `[ERROR] unknown variable 'rpl_semi_sync_slave_enabled=1'`. This variable was only set on these three servers. At this point the mysql service we were running shut down!

The fourth server did not have an identical mysql configuration. Notably, the variable `rpl_semi_sync_slave_enabled` was not present. Apt was able to install `iotop` but interestingly our mysql service did *not* restart or shut down.

So it seems that some packages, on failing to install, will kill running processes that seem tangential to the installation! This has me very wary about installing further packages on our production servers running processes that we don't like to restart whenever. How can I know whether a package install will restart these processes and why is it happening in the first place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's very unlikely that packages failing to install `kill`s anything afterwards or because of failure – related or not. Furthermore, the `[ERROR] unknown variable 'rpl_semi_sync_slave_enabled = 1;` doesn't seem like an error of `apt`, but of MySQL, during its startup.

It's perfectly possible that MySQL was restarted on all the servers, but only failed to start on one, causing the installation to fail – not vice versa.

Why would installing `iotop` cause MySQL to restart? In distributions (like your Ubuntu) we have this thing called *dependency tree*: packages can depend on other packages that depends on other packages, that can be mutually needed by yet other packages. Sometimes a package depends on certain version of another package, causing already installed package to be upgraded when installed.

In this case, `iotop` depends on `python`. Then, e.g. `python-mysqldb` depends on `python` and `libmysqlclient18` that depends on `mysql-common`... you probably got the picture why MySQL may have been upgraded alongside seemingly unrelated `iotop`.

How to know which packages gets installed and upgraded during `apt-get install`?

> `-y`, `--yes`, `--assume-yes`
>
> Automatic yes to prompts. Assume `yes` as answer to all prompts and run non-interactively. If an undesirable
>   situation, such as changing a held package or removing an essential
>   package, occurs then `apt-get` will abort.

**Do not use `-y` if you aren't absolutely sure what will happen.** By default you will get a list of all packages that gets installed, upgraded or even removed. You voluntarily choose to ignore this all.

Comment: This is correct in so many ways. It is/was a known MySQL bug, turns out. Dependencies were indeed causing the upgrade/restart partly due to a weird half-installed state of a newer version that's beyond the scope of this question. And I very much agree with the `-y` advice. Thank you.

Comment: This is why you don't let the package manager touch your MySQL Server.  Install it from the tarballs.  Your database is too important to trust anybody, including the package maintainers, to mess with its installation or upgrades.